# How to access main repository from cusom repository in Spring Data JPA?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

I am writing repository for `variables` table and wish to access specific rows with it. For this I am trying to autowire main repository into custom implementation, like this:

```
public interface VariableRepo extends CrudRepository<Variable, Long>, VariableRepoCustom {
   Variable getByName(String name);
}

public interface VariableRepoCustom {
...
   Variable getPopulationSingle();
...
}

public class VariableRepoCustomImpl implements VariableRepoCustom {

   private final VariableRepo variableRepo;

   @Autowired
   public VariableRepoCustomImpl(VariableRepo variableRepo) {
      this.variableRepo = variableRepo;
   }

   @Override
   public Variable getPopulationSingle() {
      return getByName("Population single");
   }
...
}
```

Unfortunately, Spring like to go crazy with this, throwing an exception:

> Error creating bean with name 'variableRepo': Invocation of init
>   method failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No
>   property getPopulationSingle found for type Variable!

I.e. it tries to find repository method inside entity class (`Variable`) which of course should not contained inside.

How to solve this?

Comment: You need to name your custom repo impl `VariableRepoImpl `

Answer (score 0):

What you named VariableRepoCustom/VariableRepoCustomImpl should be in fact a service (not a repository in terms of spring-data-jpa).

The interface VariableRepoCustom should not be present in JPA searchpath, to prevent JPA to generate an implementation

Comment: Moving custom... to another package didn't help.

Comment: What is your JPA searchpath ? If the interface was moved out of JPA searchpath, JPA couldn't try tout generate an implementation

Comment: you should have lines like this in your app context :   <repositories base-package="com.acme.repositories" />

Comment: I have it. Repositories work. The only thing which is not working is repo inside repo extension

Answer (score 0):

I think might be your repository impl does not have @Repository annotation. Please make both repository and impl as @Repository. it should fix your problem.

For best practice, No need to autowire `VariableRepo` interface into impl class.

Edit: 
Also remove custom from impl. The name will be RepoName by append impl. it is definition like VariableRepoImpl

Comment: I don't see this is required: http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/2.0.x/reference/html/#repositories.definition

Comment: I see, no need to autowire Repo into impl class

Comment: How to access it then?

Comment: Also remove custom from impl. The name will be RepoName by append impl. it is definition like VariableRepoImpl

Comment: I had same problem before then I saw important note here http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/2.0.x/reference/html/#repositories.single-repository-behaviour

Comment: Please change your answer to contain only `Impl` statement: this was the only problem.